# fancy boxes in jquery: how does it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I know how to use a fancy boxes and I know there are tons of them.
**My goal is to create a very simple one**, more for tutorial purposes and curiosity.

I just wonder how do they work. If I understand well, a fancy box is :

1) **disabling all events on a html page**

2) **display a semi transparent image on top**

3) display a centered div in top.

point 3 seems very clear. I just wonder how points 1 and point 2 work.

Any clue ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 and 2 are the same thing. By placing a semi-transparent overlay over the entire page (this is usually an absolutely positioned div with 100% width and height) you prevent the user from interacting with any of the inside elements.

Answer (score 0):

A light box / fancy box is essentially two divider elements; one that covers the entire page (thus the semi-transparency), and one that contains the 'pop-up' contents. There are several flavors and features common on a variety of them, but these two things are what is most essential.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/75LTD/ Like so:

```
<body style="width:100%; height:1024px;">
<div class="overlay">

    <div class="lightbox"></div>
</div>
<p>sdjfhsd</p>
</body>
​
```

CSS:

```
.overlay{width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; left:0; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); }
.lightbox{position:absolute; top:50%; margin-top:-100px; left:50%; margin-left:-100px; height:200px; width:200px; background:#FFF; border-radius:10px;}
```

​